# Why is my mesh acting strange?

Tags: mesh, bevel

I took a cube, added a few subdivisions, then used edit mode to do this[image]

You can already see it messing up at the edges, but it becomes even more clear as you zoom out

[image]

This is a cube with a few subdivisions, reshapened, and beveled at the outer edges, except for the top. Any idea why it's acting like this?

Edit : Here is the file, as you may see the more you zoom out the more it (Cube.001&2) begin to do that

Comment: so where is acting strange? maybe highlight the part you're talking about, also please show a screenshot of your wireframe, or even share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! Try checking the viewport clip settings. Open the properties panel with N, then go to the view tab and look for Clip Start and End. If the start is very small or the end is very large it can cause display issues. 0.1 and 1000 are the defaults. Are yours set to something else?

Comment: @moonboots I added my file at the very bottom, thanks

Comment: @Brenticus it happens at medium range or close as well. My clip was already lowered, and no matter how high my end was, the issue persists

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I accidentally made the cube really big, so when I zoomed out it was by a lot, so guess technically it was an issue with the clip distance. Brenticus was right.